# Why my Gdevelop game crashes when I compile with Cordova for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, frameworks

Good Morning,

I have created a game with Gdevelop. It works perfectly on Windows, MacOS and Android, but when I want to compile it to send it to Xcode and create the iOS version I get the following error:

```
juanjosegarciamanzano@macbook-pro-de-juan Jabato % cordova platform add ios
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios
Adding ios project...
Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
    Path: platforms/ios
    Package: com.stilugames.jabaliespacial
    Name: Jabali Espacial


[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleUserMessagingPlatform":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (= 2.1.0, >= 1.1)

  In Podfile:
    GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (~> 2.0.0)

Specs satisfying the `GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (~> 2.0.0), GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (= 2.1.0, >= 1.1)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I have tried a solution that I found on the internet that in principle seems to regenerate the framework:

```
juanjosegarciamanzano@macbook-pro-de-juan ios % pod install --repo-update
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing GoogleUserMessagingPlatform 2.0.1 (was 2.1.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 6 total pods installed.

[!] The `Jabali Espacial [Debug]` target overrides the `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Jabali Espacial/Pods-Jabali Espacial.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Jabali Espacial [Release]` target overrides the `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Jabali Espacial/Pods-Jabali Espacial.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
juanjosegarciamanzano@macbook-pro-de-juan ios %
```

Once this is done, the following command should work, but I get this error:

```
juanjosegarciamanzano@macbook-pro-de-juan Jabato % cordova build ios
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-purchase". Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-purchase" for ios

[!] The `Jabali Espacial [Debug]` target overrides the `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Jabali Espacial/Pods-Jabali Espacial.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

[!] The `Jabali Espacial [Release]` target overrides the `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Jabali Espacial/Pods-Jabali Espacial.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
Command failed with exit code 1: xcodebuild -version
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
juanjosegarciamanzano@macbook-pro-de-juan Jabato %
```

Could you please help me? I don't know how to solve it.

Thank you!

I only need help to get my game working on xcode.